# Regular expression to extract chemical formula and symbols

Tags: regex

is it possible to recognize or to extract only chemical formula and symbols in text, example:

```
    text text h2o, text text Ho3NiGe2, 20% 15°C text text text text
```

PS: output will be : h20, Ho3NiGe2,

Comment: Well, if you can give precise definition for "chemical formula" - it might be possible to extract it.

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: Of course, but you have to define what a formula is. E.g. `H` is a chemical formula as well. Do you have a well defined text structure or is it free text?

Comment: Note that chemical formulae are case sensitive.

Comment: Do you want to limit to CaMeL and alphanumeric words only? ALLCAPS will be ambiguous (like `SO`).

Comment: You would require a list of symbols of all elements. Then you could write a simple regular expression that matches chemical formulae. But there would be a lot of false positives. For example, H2SO4 would match, but so would H1Si24. But if your source text does not have any incorrect formulae, then you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: "text" is free text, and I can't have predefined list of chemical formula because every day we create a new chemical compound

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Do you want to following:**

**Regex:** `\b([A-Z][a-z]{0,2}\d{0,3})+`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rK0pX8/1)**

Comment: why thers is two color blue and green, what does it mean?

Comment: @tim land   These  are different group ex: `H2` & `O2` or O .  One group has (1-3) leter and (0-3) digit. these group are repeated like as `H2SO4`

Comment: thanks, but if i put the first 't' of text to 'T' I got the **Tex**t

Comment: yes, but it is simple rule. rule 1: 1st letter must be capital letter. if have more exception then it is not solved by regex. it have to solve by php `in_array` function or another way..