# A strict regular expression for matching chemical formulae

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

In the course of processing a large textual chemical database with Perl, I had been faced with the problem of using a regex to match chemical formulae. I have seen [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132327) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602175) previous topics, but the suggested answers there are too loose for my requirements.

Specifically, my (admittedly limited) research has led me to [this posting](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2016/02/04/regular-expression-to-match-a-chemical-element/#comment-927030) that gives a regex for the currently accepted chemical symbols, which I'll copy here for reference

```
[BCFHIKNOPSUVWY]|[ISZ][nr]|[ACELP][ru]|A[cglmst]|B[aehikr]|C[adeflos]|D[bsy]|Es|F[elmr]|G[ade]|H[efgos]|Kr|L[aiv]|M[cdgnot]|N[abdehiop]|O[gs]|P[abdmot]|R[abe-hnu]|S[bcegim]|T[abcehilms]|Xe|Yb
```

(Thus e.g. `C`, `Cm`, and `Cn` will pass, but not `Cg` or `Cx`.)

As with the previous questions, I also need to match numbers, complete sets of parentheses and complete sets of square brackets, so that both e.g. `C2H6O` and `(CH3)2CFCOO(CH2)2Si(CH3)2Cl` are matched.

So how do I combine the previous solutions with the grand regex for matching valid chemical elements to strictly match a chemical formula?

(If it's not too much trouble to add, a blow-by-blow account of how to humanly parse the regex would be appreciated greatly, though not strictly necessary.)

Comment: To be honest, a regex alone probably won't cover validating all chemical expressions.  The reason for this is that a chemical formula may have nested parenthesis of arbitrary depth.  Instead a parser might be more appropriate here.

Comment: This seems a little insane. Chemists don't follow strict syntactic rules when writing such formulae. Organic chemists will often throw an `R` in there to represent an arbitrary carbon-based group, or a `Ph` for a phenyl group, or an `X` for a halide, and on and on and on. That's just a tiny tase of the potential irregularities. Are you SURE you have to do this?

Comment: @Chris To add to that, simply because a formula passes the regex does not mean that the molecule actually exists.  There are many layers of validation here.

Comment: Presumably the text the OP is using is responsible for knowing its chemistry, and the goal is just to identify when the text is expressing a formula. But still...

Comment: Hello @Chris, in this application at least, I do not have to deal with variable groups or standard group abbreviations like `en` or `Me`, as they were disallowed in the application I have. But you are right that one should be wary of those special situations in the most general case.

Comment: @Tim, for my purposes, the depth of parenthesization/ bracketing is limited to two; e.g. `[(CH3)2CH]2BCH2I`. And yes, these are records of synthesized substances, so they certainly do exist.

Comment: I believe (not totally sure otherwise I would post an answer) that your requirement to match complete sets of parentheses is a big indication that you need a parser. A parser has state and can know things like "I'm in a parenthetical now" and therefore make sense of closing them again.

Comment: (I was also going to ask at the chemistry site, but figure that there are too few people there who know regexes.)

Comment: @Krissy The point here is that a simple regex probably cannot handle nested parentheses.  You need a parser.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The Perl and PCRE regex engines are capable of handling recursive syntax. Speaking formally, they can recognize at least all `LL(*)` (LL-regular) languages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Brief

I decided why not create a massive regex to do what you want (but still maintain a clean regex). This regex would be used in conjunction with a loop to go over matches for bracket or parentheses groups.

---

### Assumptions

I am assuming the following since the OP has not given a full list of positive and negative matches:

- Nested parentheses aren't possible
- Nested square brackets aren't possible
- Square bracket groups that surround a single parentheses group are redundant and therefore incorrect
- Square bracket groups must contain at least 2 groups, of which 1 such group must be a parentheses group

If any of these assumptions are incorrect, please let me know so that I may fix the regex accordingly

---

### Answer

**[View this regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/UjOvca/4)**

#### Code

```
(?(DEFINE)
  (?# Periodic elements )
  (?<Hydrogen>H)
  (?<Helium>He)
  (?<Lithium>Li)
  (?<Beryllium>Be)
  (?<Boron>B)
  (?<Carbon>C)
  (?<Nitrogen>N)
  (?<Oxygen>O)
  (?<Fluorine>F)
  (?<Neon>Ne)
  (?<Sodium>Na)
  (?<Magnesium>Mg)
  (?<Aluminum>Al)
  (?<Silicon>Si)
  (?<Phosphorus>P)
  (?<Sulfur>S)
  (?<Chlorine>Cl)
  (?<Argon>Ar)
  (?<Potassium>K)
  (?<Calcium>Ca)
  (?<Scandium>Sc)
  (?<Titanium>Ti)
  (?<Vanadium>V)
  (?<Chromium>Cr)
  (?<Manganese>Mn)
  (?<Iron>Fe)
  (?<Cobalt>Co)
  (?<Nickel>Ni)
  (?<Copper>Cu)
  (?<Zinc>Zn)
  (?<Gallium>Ga)
  (?<Germanium>Ge)
  (?<Arsenic>As)
  (?<Selenium>Se)
  (?<Bromine>Br)
  (?<Krypton>Kr)
  (?<Rubidium>Rb)
  (?<Strontium>Sr)
  (?<Yttrium>Y)
  (?<Zirconium>Zr)
  (?<Niobium>Nb)
  (?<Molybdenum>Mo)
  (?<Technetium>Tc)
  (?<Ruthenium>Ru)
  (?<Rhodium>Rh)
  (?<Palladium>Pd)
  (?<Silver>Ag)
  (?<Cadmium>Cd)
  (?<Indium>In)
  (?<Tin>Sn)
  (?<Antimony>Sb)
  (?<Tellurium>Te)
  (?<Iodine>I)
  (?<Xenon>Xe)
  (?<Cesium>Cs)
  (?<Barium>Ba)
  (?<Lanthanum>La)
  (?<Cerium>Ce)
  (?<Praseodymium>Pr)
  (?<Neodymium>Nd)
  (?<Promethium>Pm)
  (?<Samarium>Sm)
  (?<Europium>Eu)
  (?<Gadolinium>Gd)
  (?<Terbium>Tb)
  (?<Dysprosium>Dy)
  (?<Holmium>Ho)
  (?<Erbium>Er)
  (?<Thulium>Tm)
  (?<Ytterbium>Yb)
  (?<Lutetium>Lu)
  (?<Hafnium>Hf)
  (?<Tantalum>Ta)
  (?<Tungsten>W)
  (?<Rhenium>Re)
  (?<Osmium>Os)
  (?<Iridium>Ir)
  (?<Platinum>Pt)
  (?<Gold>Au)
  (?<Mercury>Hg)
  (?<Thallium>Tl)
  (?<Lead>Pb)
  (?<Bismuth>Bi)
  (?<Polonium>Po)
  (?<Astatine>At)
  (?<Radon>Rn)
  (?<Francium>Fr)
  (?<Radium>Ra)
  (?<Actinium>Ac)
  (?<Thorium>Th)
  (?<Protactinium>Pa)
  (?<Uranium>U)
  (?<Neptunium>Np)
  (?<Plutonium>Pu)
  (?<Americium>Am)
  (?<Curium>Cm)
  (?<Berkelium>Bk)
  (?<Californium>Cf)
  (?<Einsteinium>Es)
  (?<Fermium>Fm)
  (?<Mendelevium>Md)
  (?<Nobelium>No)
  (?<Lawrencium>Lr)
  (?<Rutherfordium>Rf)
  (?<Dubnium>Db)
  (?<Seaborgium>Sg)
  (?<Bohrium>Bh)
  (?<Hassium>Hs)
  (?<Meitnerium>Mt)
  (?<Darmstadtium>Ds)
  (?<Roentgenium>Rg)
  (?<Copernicium>Cn)
  (?<Nihonium>Nh)
  (?<Flerovium>Fl)
  (?<Moscovium>Mc)
  (?<Livermorium>Lv)
  (?<Tennessine>Ts)
  (?<Oganesson>Og)
  (?# Regex )
  (?<Element>(?&Actinium)|(?&Silver)|(?&Aluminum)|(?&Americium)|(?&Argon)|(?&Arsenic)|(?&Astatine)|(?&Gold)|(?&Barium)|(?&Beryllium)|(?&Bohrium)|(?&Bismuth)|(?&Berkelium)|(?&Bromine)|(?&Boron)|(?&Calcium)|(?&Cadmium)|(?&Cerium)|(?&Californium)|(?&Chlorine)|(?&Curium)|(?&Copernicium)|(?&Cobalt)|(?&Chromium)|(?&Cesium)|(?&Copper)|(?&Carbon)|(?&Dubnium)|(?&Darmstadtium)|(?&Dysprosium)|(?&Erbium)|(?&Einsteinium)|(?&Europium)|(?&Iron)|(?&Flerovium)|(?&Fermium)|(?&Francium)|(?&Fluorine)|(?&Gallium)|(?&Gadolinium)|(?&Germanium)|(?&Helium)|(?&Hafnium)|(?&Mercury)|(?&Holmium)|(?&Hassium)|(?&Hydrogen)|(?&Indium)|(?&Iridium)|(?&Iodine)|(?&Krypton)|(?&Potassium)|(?&Lanthanum)|(?&Lithium)|(?&Lawrencium)|(?&Lutetium)|(?&Livermorium)|(?&Moscovium)|(?&Mendelevium)|(?&Magnesium)|(?&Manganese)|(?&Molybdenum)|(?&Meitnerium)|(?&Sodium)|(?&Niobium)|(?&Neodymium)|(?&Neon)|(?&Nihonium)|(?&Nickel)|(?&Nobelium)|(?&Neptunium)|(?&Nitrogen)|(?&Oganesson)|(?&Osmium)|(?&Oxygen)|(?&Protactinium)|(?&Lead)|(?&Palladium)|(?&Promethium)|(?&Polonium)|(?&Praseodymium)|(?&Platinum)|(?&Plutonium)|(?&Phosphorus)|(?&Radium)|(?&Rubidium)|(?&Rhenium)|(?&Rutherfordium)|(?&Roentgenium)|(?&Rhodium)|(?&Radon)|(?&Ruthenium)|(?&Antimony)|(?&Scandium)|(?&Selenium)|(?&Seaborgium)|(?&Silicon)|(?&Samarium)|(?&Tin)|(?&Strontium)|(?&Sulfur)|(?&Tantalum)|(?&Terbium)|(?&Technetium)|(?&Tellurium)|(?&Thorium)|(?&Titanium)|(?&Thallium)|(?&Thulium)|(?&Tennessine)|(?&Uranium)|(?&Vanadium)|(?&Tungsten)|(?&Xenon)|(?&Ytterbium)|(?&Yttrium)|(?&Zirconium)|(?&Zinc))
  (?<Num>(?:[1-9]\d*)?)
  (?<ElementGroup>(?:(?&Element)(?&Num))+)
  (?<ElementParenthesesGroup>\((?&ElementGroup)+\)(?&Num))
  (?<ElementSquareBracketGroup>\[(?:(?:(?&ElementParenthesesGroup)(?:(?&ElementGroup)|(?&ElementParenthesesGroup))+)|(?:(?:(?&ElementGroup)|(?&ElementParenthesesGroup))+(?&ElementParenthesesGroup)))\](?&Num))
)
^((?<Brackets>(?&ElementSquareBracketGroup))|(?<Parentheses>(?&ElementParenthesesGroup))|(?<Group>(?&ElementGroup)))+$
```

#### Explanation

1. The first part of the `(?(DEFINE))` section lists each periodic element (ordered by atomic number for easy lookup).
2. The `Element` group acts as a simple or `|` between each of the elements listed in 1. ensuring that each element's symbol is ordered alphabetically by the first character, and then by symbol character length (so as not to catch, for example, Carbon `C` instead of Calcium `Ca`)
3. `ElementGroup` specifies a group of chemicals in the format: one or more `Element` followed by zero or more digits, excluding zero (specified by the group `Num`)

   - **Valid Examples**

     - `C` - `Element`
     - `CH` - `Element` followed by another `Element`
     - `CH3` -`Element` followed by another `Element` and a `Num`
     - `O2` - `Element` followed by a `Num`
   - **Invalid Examples**

     - `N0` - `0` cannot be used explicitly
     - `N01` - `Num` group specifies the number must begin with `1-9` or not have a number
     - `A` - Element does not exist
     - `c` - Element does not exist - case sensitive regex
4. `ElementParenthesesGroup` specifies one or more groupings of `ElementGroup` between parentheses `(` `)` but containing at least one `ElementGroup`

   - **Valid Examples**

     - `(CH)` - `ElementGroup` surrounded by parentheses
     - `(CH3)` - `ElementGroup` surrounded by parentheses
     - `(CH3NO4)` - multiple `ElementGroup` surrounded by parentheses
     - `(CH3N04)2` - multiple `ElementGroup` surrounded by parentheses followed by a `Num`
   - **Invalid Examples**

     - `(CH[NO4])` - Only `ElementGroup` is valid inside `ElementParenthesesGroup`
5. `ElementSquareBracketGroup` specifies a grouping of `ElementParenthesesGroup` or `ElementGroup` between square brackets `[` `]` but containing at least one `ElementParenthesesGroup` and one other group (`ElementParenthesesGroup` or `ElementGroup`)

   - **Valid Examples**

     - `[CH3(NO4)]` - Contains at least one `ElementParenthesesGroup` and one other `ElementParenthesesGroup` or `ElementGroup`
     - `[(NO4)CH]2` - Contains at least one `ElementParenthesesGroup` and one other `ElementParenthesesGroup` or `ElementGroup` followed by `Num`
     - `[(NO4)(CH3)]` - Contains at least one `ElementParenthesesGroup` and one other `ElementParenthesesGroup` or `ElementGroup`
   - **Invalid Examples**

     - `[(NO4)]` - Does not contain second group, brackets `[` `]` are redundant
     - `[NO4]` - Does not contain `ElementParenthesesGroup`

#### Additional Information

I realize this is a very long answer, but the OP is asking a very specific question and wants to ensure specific criteria are met.

Ensure the following flags are set:

- `g` - ensures global matches
- `x`  - ensures whitespace is ignored
- if the data is across multiple lines (separated by a newline character) use `m` for multi line

Note: Regex will only capture the last group of type `X` that it finds (and overwrite the previously captured group of said type `X`. This is the default behaviour of regex and there is no way to currently override this behaviour. This may give you undesirable results. You can see this with the last example in the linked regex as well as with your example of `(CH3)2CFCOO(CH2)2Si(CH3)2Cl` since there are multiple of each group type.

Comment: Nice layout. I've added the current names instead of the provisional names. Nevertheless, will try this tomorrow at work!

Comment: @KrissyBudd Thanks! Do you want to keep the old element symbols as well? I can add back in `Uub`, `Uut`, etc. under the new element names. This would appear as, for example `(?<Copernicium>Cn|Uub)`

Comment: No, I think I would prefer that only the current names be used. (We have already done a search and replace in that regard.)

Comment: @KrissyBudd Perfect! I'll update the link on regex101 with the same information as the regex here

Answer (score 5):

It is best not to assemble such a large regex manually. Instead, let's assume we have an array of atoms `@atoms`. We can then create a regex matching any of these atoms like:

```
my ($atoms_regex) = map qr/$_/, join '|', map quotemeta, sort @atoms;
```

(Sort all items so that shorter atom names come first, then escape all items with `quotemeta`, join them with a `|` for alternatives, and compile the regex.)

You can add any used abbreviations to the `@atoms` array.

Next, we can write a regex that allows grouping and numbering. Our regex will match any number of items, where an item may be an atom or a group, and may be followed by a number:

```
my $chemical_formula_regex = qr/
  (?&item)++
  (?(DEFINE)
    (?<item> (?: \((?&item)++\) | \[(?&item)++\] | $atoms_regex ) [0-9]* )
  )
/x;
```

- Within the `(?(DEFINE) ...)` group we can define named subpatterns with `(?<name> ...)`. A subpattern is like a subroutine for a regex. We can call those subpatterns with `(?&name)`. This allows us to structure the regex without unnecessary repetition.
- The `/x` flag allows us to use whitespace and linebreaks and comments to lay out the regex in a more readable fashion. Regexes don't have to be an incomprehensible mess!
- The `++` quantifier instead of `+` is not strictly necessary, but prevents unwanted backtracking. That may be a bit faster when a match fails.

Answer (score 0):

Since this post is a top result for "regex chemistry symbols", I would also like to submit a solution. It is a python script that uses a regex to match chemistry formulas of the type A#B#, where A and B are chemical symbols and # is a number. The script as implemented matches and then surrounds the matches with \ce{} for use in LaTeX. It also includes the ability to exclude matches if the capture is in a user-defined list, which means words such as "I" and "In" will not be matched. [Gist Link](https://gist.github.com/mtesseracted/9107768aa5d8018ec4b63c59ce7ca41a).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Find chemical symbols and surround them with \ce{ Symbol }
# Problem words: I, HOW, In, degrees K. Add words to exlist to ignore them.

import re, sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2 :
  print('Usage:> {} <filename>'.format(sys.argv[0]))
  sys.exit(1)

ptable =" H                                                                  He "
ptable+=" Li  Be                                         B   C   N   O   F   Ne "
ptable+=" Na  Mg                                         Al  Si  P   S   Cl  Ar "
ptable+=" K   Ca  Sc  Ti  V   Cr  Mn  Fe  Co  Ni  Cu  Zn Ga  Ge  As  Se  Br  Kr "
ptable+=" Rb  Sr  Y   Zr  Nb  Mo  Tc  Ru  Rh  Pd  Ag  Cd In  Sn  Sb  Te  I   Xe "
ptable+=" Cs  Ba  La  Hf  Ta  W   Re  Os  Ir  Pt  Au  Hg Tl  Pb  Bi  Po  At  Rn "
ptable+=" Fr  Ra  Ac  Rf  Db  Sg  Bh  Hs  Mt  Ds  Rg  Cn Nh  Fl  Mc  Lv  Ts  Og "
ptable+="             Ce  Pr  Nd  Pm  Sm  Eu  Gd  Tb  Dy Ho  Er  Tm  Yb  Lu     "
ptable+="             Th  Pa  U   Np  Pu  Am  Cm  Bk  Cf Es  Fm  Md  No  Lr     "

exlist = ['C','I','In','K','HOW'] # exclude these words from being replaced
orsyms = '|'.join(ptable.split())
resyms = re.compile(r'\b'+'((?:(?:{})\d*)+)'.format(orsyms)+r'\b')

latexfile=sys.argv[1]
with open(latexfile,'r') as fd:
    for line in fd:

        for m in list(set(resyms.findall(line))):
            if m not in exlist :
                line = re.sub(r'\b'+m+r'\b', r'\ce{'+m+r'}', line)

        print(line,end='')
```